# Multiple arguments with values to custom management command

Tags: python, django, django-management-command

How do I pass multiple arguments with values, from command line, to a custom django management command?

```
def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument('str_arg1', nargs='+')
    parser.add_argument('int_arg2', nargs='+', type=int)
```

When I run:

```
./manage.py my_command str_arg1 value int_arg2 1 --settings=config.settings.local
```

I get the following values in `options`:

```
options['str_arg1'] = ['str_arg1', 'value', 'int_arg2']
options['int_arg2'] = [1]
```

Tried searching in documentation and online for a solution and multiple ways of passing the arguments with no luck. Django version is 1.10.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way you have defined the arguments means they are *positional* arguments.  There's no sensible way to have multiple positional arguments which consume an unknown amount of values.

Modify your parser to specify them as options instead:

```
parser.add_argument('--str-arg1', nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('--int-arg2', nargs='+', type=int)
```

And modify the call:

```
./manage.py my_command --str-arg1 value --int-arg2 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick. So simple. Any idea why it would put the values into lists? I'm now retrieving them using `options['str_arg1'][0]`

Comment: When you use `nargs='+'`, argparse will always store the values into list.  `+` means "there may be one or more values for this argument".  If you know you only want to consume exactly one value, you could omit that `nargs='+'`.